# Using height() of dynamic menu to determine location for tag insert

Tags: jquery, height

Any help would be greatly appreciated -

- take - 
  **HEIGHT** = height of table of contents menu
- apply - 
  **MEASURE** = measure DOWN (above height) from top of content container div with class=wiki-content
- put - 
  **INSERT** = place an empty DIV tag a distance equal to menu height + 100px -

**NOTE:** This is very different than simply inserting the tag after the closing div tag of the table of contents menu. The height calculation is what determines placement. To date the editors add the DIV tag after the TOC manually.

Comment: try .append(). And post some HTML

Comment: If you just want to put it after the menu, `.insertAfter()` would work fine, and you wouldn't need `menuheight`.

Comment: NOTE: I should have made clearer that the height x width of the menu; a 190px column that is floated right - so content wraps around this menu, and it varies in length. But, certain block elements, headers, and tables don't wrap and just go underneath the menu. So when an editor adds a menu widget to a page for creating this table of contents, it also adds CSS that removes the design elements of the headers that extend full width, like borders & Background shading. - So far editors are manually placing a macro in the content area below the bottom of the menu, this resets the styles for headers

Comment: - So the tag does not simply go after the menu's html tag, it goes somewhere in the content below wherever the bottom of the menu reaches to.